# How to a swap only some members of a struct in a vector?

Tags: vector, rust

Vectors have a method to swap entire items:

```
my_vector.swap(i, j)
```

For a vector of large structs, I want to swap only some of the data in each struct.

What would be a *rustic* way to swap only *some* members of the struct?

Answer (score 3):

You need to break the slice into disjoint subsets using [`[_]::split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut).  This can be used to get `&mut _`s to the structures.  At that point, you can just [`mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html) the elements as needed.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Big {
    small: i32,
    tiny: u8,
}

fn swap_smalls(bigs: &mut [Big], i: usize, j: usize) {
    use std::cmp::{max, min};
    use std::mem::swap;

    if i == j { return; }
    let (i, j) = (min(i, j), max(i, j));

    let (left_slice, right_slice) = bigs.split_at_mut(j);
    let left = &mut left_slice[i];
    let right = &mut right_slice[0];

    swap(&mut left.small, &mut right.small);
}

fn main() {
    let mut bigs = vec![
        Big { small: 4, tiny: 31 },
        Big { small: 0, tiny: 2 },
        Big { small: -7, tiny: 193 },
    ];

    println!("before: {:?}", bigs);
    swap_smalls(&mut bigs, 0, 2);
    println!("after:  {:?}", bigs);
}
```

Outputs:

```
before: [Big { small: 4, tiny: 31 }, Big { small: 0, tiny: 2 }, Big { small: -7, tiny: 193 }]
after:  [Big { small: -7, tiny: 31 }, Big { small: 0, tiny: 2 }, Big { small: 4, tiny: 193 }]
```

*"rustic"* implies there are multiple solutions, but I don't think there *are*, so it's not really relevant.